# How many reputation points need for upvoting?

Tags: discussion, voting, privileges

The most probably this is a duplicate, but I wasn't able to find it. (Sorry for this.)

> How many points are needed to allow users to upvote?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 6, accepted):

15 for registered users, and unregistered users cannot vote.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. (What's the difference between registered and unregistered users? I mean, how can I have an username on this site, but in the same time it is unregistered?)

Comment: A registered user "signed up" at some point (using an OpenID account they have from elsewhere or createing one with SE). It is also possible to "post as a guest" (visit the "ask question" site while not logged in to see what I mean). If you do so, you get a "cookie" that allows you to interact with you post while cookie is active. You can even use it to post another post as the same unregistered user as long as you keep it. You can tell the difference by visiting the user's page, for unregistered ones it says this.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68524/what-does-it-mean-when-someones-an-unregistered-user